# mysqldump is not dumping my data

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I am running mysqldump on Ubuntu Linux (10.0.4 LTS)

my mySQL version info is:

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.41, for debian-linux-gnu (i486) using readline 6.1

I used the following command:

**mysql -u username -p dbname > dbname_backup.sql**

However when I opened the generated .sql file, I saw that most of the tables had only the schema dumped and in the few cases where the actual data was dumped, only 1 or two records were dumped (there are ATLEAST several tens of records in each table).

Does anyone know what maybe going on?

Comment: mysql -u username -p dbname > dbname_backup.sql ? It should be mysqldump -u username ....

Answer (score 5):

I think you expect to see a lot of inserts and probably you see only 1 or 2. Is normal, if you look closer you will see 1 or 2 BIG inserts (extended inserts). Extended inserts are multiple row inserts which includes several VALUES lists.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how many rows do most extended inserts contain?

Comment: I think mysqldump calculate that depending on how many data is in tables.

Answer (score 2):

Try passing the full command instead:

`mysqldump --databases --result-file=filename.sql mydatabase -u mysqluser -p`

Answer (score 2):

I also had the problem that data was not dumped, but not for the same reason. Posting an answer here in case someone makes the same mistake. I did:

`mysqldump -u user -p -d database_name`

thinking that `-d database_name` specifies the db name. However database_name is considered as last argument (and not an option), while `-d` seems to be an (undocumented) standalone abbreviation for `--no-data`. After I removed `-d` I got the data in the dump.